# How can i Uniquely identify the Views in n No of Fragments in a same Activity.?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` **FragmentPassengerDetails.java**

```
public class FragmentPassengerDetails extends Fragment {


    View viewGroup;
    public EditText et_name;
    View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        this.viewGroup=container;
        this.view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_passengers_info, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        et_name=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_tester);
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I have Created an `Activity`. In which I used this fragment based on some Conditions(seatsSelected)

```
for(i=1;i<=seatsSelected.size();i++){
            //Initializing frame layout
            FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
            framelayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            Log.d("Result", "--------------------------------------------------------Setting Dynamic ID to Fragments: "+i);
            framelayout.setId(i);
            passengerContainerLayout.addView(framelayout);
            framelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I am "+v.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            FragmentPassengerDetails fragmentPassengerDetails=new FragmentPassengerDetails();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(i,fragmentPassengerDetails,"frag"+i);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();



        }
```

In this I can able to Achieve  Dynamic Fragments.But can't able to refer the `EditText` with in the `Fragment` by the Following Code

```
 FragmentPassengerDetails fragmentPassengerDetails=new FragmentPassengerDetails();
            View v=fragmentPassengerDetails.getView();
            Log.d("Fragment", "---------------------------------View Obtained: "+v);

            EditText tv=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.et_tester);
            tv.setText("WrRWRWRWRWR");
```

It Always throws **java.lang.NullPointerException:**

How can i get rid of this and how can i Uniquely identify the `EditTextViews`..?? Any Help Please....!!

Answer (score 0):

While the FragmentPassengerDetails class has been instantiated in the last block of code in your question, its View has not yet been created, that will only happen after you add it using the FragmentManager and the appropriate lifecycle methods are executed, in this case `onCreateView()`.

It seems you're going about this the wrong way though.

I would suggest passing data to the FragmentPassengerDetails instance when it is created. The the Fragment can use that data in `onCreateView()` to render itself.

Have a look at **`Fragment.setArguments(Bundle)`** which can be used to set the data and `Fragment.getArguments()` which can be called from within `onCreateView()` to retrieve the data.

Comment: @dammason  I did the same as you have mentioned here.the problem is **`onCreateView()`** was invoked random number of times

Comment: Looking at your code it should be invoked exactly `seatsSelected.size()` times. You have control over the arguments passed to each instance of the Fragment you create. Then the Fragment can execute the same code to handle the data passed to it.